# A teacher randomly selects $6$ students to present, what are the odds that $3$ girls and $3$ boys are selected?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A teacher randomly selects $6$ students to present, what are the odds that $3$ girls and $3$ boys are selected? There are $12$ girls and $19$ boys.

I think the answers is $\frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18} \cdot \frac{1}{17}$,
but I also have a feeling it is $\frac{\dbinom{12}{3}\dbinom{19}{3}}{\dbinom{31}{6}}$.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please use mathjax.

Comment: Please take some time to read the Help pages here on math.SE. In particular, see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: The first equation would be true if you wanted to know the probability that $3$ _particular_ girls and $3$ _particular_ boys were chosen, and if the order mattered. Since order doesn't matter, and the $3$ boys and $3$ girls can be any $4$, an answer involving "choose" makes more sense. Can you try to justify why the second answer is correct?

Comment: On second though the numerator may be 12C3+19C3, because that gives the number of ways to select 3 girls from a total of 12 and 19 boys from a total of 3, over the total ways to choose 6 from 31 students.

Comment: Sometimes second thoughts are no so great.

Answer (score 1):

Your second answer is correct.

The probability of selecting three boys and three girls when six students are selected is the number of ways a subset of three of the nineteen boys and a subset of three of the twelve girls can be selected when a subset of six of the thirty-one students is selected.

$$\frac{\dbinom{19}{3}\dbinom{12}{3}}{\dbinom{31}{6}}$$

As @kccu remarked in the comments, your answer 
$$\frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18} \cdot \frac{1}{17}$$
is the number of ways of selecting three particular girls and three particular boys in that order.  However, the order in which the students is selected does not matter.  What does matter is which students are selected.  Therefore, we are considering subsets.